# Export dataset to LaTeX

Tags: latex, stata

I am trying to export summary statistics that are saved as variables in the main dataset from Stata to LaTeX using the *community-contributed* command `esttab`. Here is the code:

```
sysuse auto, clear
collapse (sum) price mpg, by(make)
estpost tabstat price mpg, by(make)
esttab
```

The `estpost tabstat` command generates exactly the table I want to create in LaTeX but `esttab` only generates an empty table.

I also posted this question on [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1478076-export-summary-statistics-saved-as-variables-to-latex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
sysuse auto, clear
collapse (sum) price mpg, by(make)
estpost tabstat price mpg, by(make)
matrix A = e(price)', e(mpg)'
esttab matrix(A), title("Summary statistics: mean") nomtitle
```

```
Summary statistics: mean
--------------------------------------
                    price          mpg
--------------------------------------
1                    4099           22
2                    4749           17
3                    3799           22
4                    9690           17
5                    6295           23
6                    9735           25
7                    4816           20
8                    7827           15
9                    5788           18
10                   4453           26
11                   5189           20
12                  10372           16
13                   4082           19
14                  11385           14
15                  14500           14
16                  15906           21
17                   3299           29
18                   5705           16
19                   4504           22
20                   5104           22
21                   3667           24
22                   3955           19
23                   6229           23
24                   4589           35
25                   5079           24
26                   8129           21
27                   3984           30
28                   4010           18
29                   5886           16
30                   6342           17
31                   4296           21
32                   4389           28
33                   4187           21
34                   5799           25
35                   4499           28
36                  11497           12
37                  13594           12
38                  13466           14
39                   3995           30
40                   3829           22
41                   5379           14
42                   6165           15
43                   4516           18
44                   6303           14
45                   3291           20
46                   8814           21
47                   5172           19
48                   4733           19
49                   4890           18
50                   4181           19
51                   4195           24
52                  10371           16
53                  12990           14
54                   4647           28
55                   4425           34
56                   4482           25
57                   6486           26
58                   4060           18
59                   5798           18
60                   4934           18
61                   5222           19
62                   4723           19
63                   4424           19
64                   4172           24
65                   3895           26
66                   3798           35
67                   5899           18
68                   3748           31
69                   5719           18
70                   7140           23
71                   5397           41
72                   4697           25
73                   6850           25
74                  11995           17
Total            6165.257      21.2973
--------------------------------------
```